# How to view history of git subtree?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have two repos (let's call them oldrepo1 and oldrepo2).  These two repos have 20k and 21k commits respectively in their current history.  I'm merging them together in a new repo, each one under a subdir:

newrepo/oldrepo1

newrepo/oldrepo2

I've used these commands to populate the new repo

`git subtree add --message="Migrate oldrepo1" --prefix=oldrepo1 <oldrepo1 url> master`

`git subtree add --message="Migrate oldrepo2" --prefix=oldrepo2 <oldrepo2 url> master`

when I go into the root of newrepo, and run "git --no-pager log --graph --oneline" I get 41k commits, as expected, but if I drill down to any level underneath and run git log all I get is the "Migrate oldrepoX" commit:

For instance, I have a file that has had 60 changes in the original repo, but when I run git log on that same file in the new repo, all I get is:

```
commit <commitid>
  Author: Me <me@myselfandi.com>
  Date:   Fri Sep 18 23:17:28 2020 -0700

      Migrate oldrepo1

      git-subtree-dir: oldrepo1
      git-subtree-mainline: <somecommitid>
      git-subtree-split: <somecommitid>
```

I didn't squash any history when I migrated, so why can't I see the 60 commits to this file in the new repo?

Answer (score 0):

> when I run git log on that same file ...

You did not show the actual command that you used, but let's suppose, for instance, that it is:

```
git log path/to/file.ext
```

or:

```
(cd path; git log to/file.ext)
```

which both do the same thing.  More generally any `git log` command that includes a *path* will do this.

The *this* in question is called History Simplification (see [Git log history simplification, elaborations example in git log's manual](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35133762/1256452)).  [The `git log` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) has been improved recently (in [commit `8d049e182e2e...`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d049e182e2e213a012e2d6839becfe0e2de79db)), so see that as well.  This history simplification can only follow a single file or path through renames, will miss some cases, and generally requires using the `--follow` option.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that `git subtree add` is a particularly difficult case, for which even `--follow` doesn't help (usually).  The existing `--follow` option is a horrible hack that really needs to be replaced, but this has been true for more than a decade and a good replacement is *hard*.

Comment: I'm moving deep into the tree and running git log on a specific file:

cd some/deeper/path

git log file.ext

which only gives me the subtree commit 


I tried with the --follow option and got no output at all

Comment: It all comes out the same: `git log file.ext` resolves the path relative to the repository root, so from that point on it is looking for a file named `some/deeper/path/file.ext`. Because `git subtree` reads the file in at that path, but earlier commits have a *different path*, the file name isn't the same. Remember that in Git, the file isn't named `file.ext`, it's named `some/deeper/path/file.ext`, complete with slashes. The `--follow` will detect if its name changes from one commit to another, and try to follow the new name. This won't catch all cases.

Comment: I also tried `git log --full-history file.ext`, and got the same single commit for the subtree add.

Comment: The case from `git subtree add` is particularly difficult here so in general you won't be able to see the file in earlier commits. To fix this, modify the `git log` source code so that it can detect this kind of case, and then you'll be able to see the file in earlier commits. (This is extremely non-trivial!)

Comment: In the original repository—whose commits are now in the combined repository—the file had the path name without the prefix. If you ask `git log` to look for *that* path, it should find the file, but you'll only see those commits that modify the file under its *old name*.

Comment: There's surely got to be some way of seeing this history without hacking git itself.  These are repos in Azure, so I can't control anything about how Azure itself is showing history.

Comment: How to ask git log for that path?  if I give git log any path, it tries to find that path in the local file system, so asking it for a path that is not the actual file path errors out with "unknown revision or path not in the working tree"

Comment: *How to ask git log for that path?* That's the $64,000 ($1 million?) question. There isn't a way to do it today. The history in a Git repository is the set of commits in the repository. The answer is in there. There's just no way to *ask for it*. If you *know* the answer, though, use `git log <options> -- <historic-path>`. The `--` tells Git: *the rest of these are path names*. Otherwise Git tries to guess whether that's a revision or a path, and it doesn't work as either one *based on the current commit*.

Answer (score 0):

I opted for a different approach, using git-filter-repo to remap each repo into subfolders and merge those modified repos into the new repo, as described by x-yuri in this discussion:

[How to import existing Git repository into another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683531/how-to-import-existing-git-repository-into-another/43345686#43345686)

with the details further spelled out here:

https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/6161d90d1af8ebac6e560bcef548c1c3

Answer (score -3):

Just add --pretty="full" to your log command:
`git log --pretty="full" path/to/file.ext`